# Flutter Isar Database store unsupported types

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

I'm currently using Hive because some of my models have TimeOfDay fields that aren't natively supported, but with type adapters I store them as strings and easily decode them. I'd like to switch to Isar because of its benefits over Hive. But since v3 Isar removed the type adapters. Is there a workaround?

I already have methods to serialize and deserialize the objects as JSONs. But cannot find a way to interact with them on isar.